# A function with a single if statement returns a display, a function without multiple ifs does not

Tags: reactjs

I have a function that contains a single If statement that returns values accordingly.

```
  const displayMovements = () => {
  return(
  movements.map((e) => {
    if (e.equipment == availableEquipment && e.movementPattern == selectedMovementPattern) {
      console.log(e.movement + " matches")
      return(
        <h6 key={e.movement}>{e.movement}</h6>
      )
    }
  })
)
```

}

Another function is similar, but contains multiple If statements that do not display anything, although the console.log() *does* display accordingly.

```
  const functionTwo= () => {
  return(
  movements.map((m) => {
    availableEquipment.map((e) => {
      if (m.equipment == e) {
        if (m.movementPattern == selectedMovementPattern) {
          console.log(m.movement + " matches")
          return(
            <h6 key={m.movement}>{m.movement}</h6>
          )
        }
      }
    })
  })
)
}
```

Both functions are being called in an identical manner.

Comment: Without a reproducible example it is difficult to say what exactly is wrong.  If I had to take a guess though, it is would be that it is something with the react component lifecycle (your state is being updated but render is not triggered for some reason).  If you add more code(a reproducible example) I can take another look.

Comment: You are missing a return statement in the second function. You need `return availableEquipment.map()...` as `movements.map()` is not returning anything. It also looks like you might want to use `availableEquipment.forEach()` instead of `map`